# How to find primary key in "DataFrame" object?

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqJFg.jpg)

Hi, how can test that the Phone is a key? it's mean there is not one phone number for at least two persons or one person has at least two different number?

Answer (score 1):

If it's unique key, then length of row axis should equal count of unique values.

```py
x = df.shape[0]
l = df['Phone'].drop_duplicates().shape[0]
assert x == l
```

Based on your full problem statement, you most likely need to use Name and Phone together to create the unique index.

```py
x = df.shape[0]
l = df[['Name', 'Phone']].drop_duplicates().shape[0]
assert x == l
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, if three is one number for every person and reverse there is no need  to  mix them. I want to find that

Comment: there is one number  for one person and reverse

Comment: Great. In that case it's your call for which column to use as the primary key based on the context of your case. People can have the same name, but not phone number. Use Phone.

Comment: I find one number for two names, but I want to check out for all of them

Answer (score 1):

`set_index()` has a parameter `verify_integrity` that raises ValueError if you have duplicate keys:

```
# has duplicate phone number; raises value error
df = pd.DataFrame({'phones': [123, 234, 345, 345],
                  'names': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
df = df.set_index('phones', 
                   verify_integrity=True)
```